# Response.json() on http error handling in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

[error-handling](https://angular.cn/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) shows how to handle errors as follows:

```
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Promise.reject(errMsg);
}
```

When I removed InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(HeroData) from the imports of @NgModule, I got the error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

This happened at `const body = error.json() || '';`
How should I deal with this situation? 
I tried to use try/catch block. I think it isn't a good practice. What's the best way?

**[A sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/bwjBng0KxwflpzKwWjpG?p=preview)** in Plunker

## **Possible reason:**

In Postman,
I use the local url to access `/app/heroes`, I got:

```
Cannot GET /heroes
```

and I use the plunker url to access `/app/heroes`, I got:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
```

So the message shows:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
or
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a _full_ URL to access the API? Do you even have an API server set up? What exactly are you trying to do here after you remove the in-memory DB?

Comment: @peeskillet I think the http will insert the host befort the relative path. but I don't know how it does.

Comment: Are the server and app on exact same host and port? Are you sure the correct URL pa the for the server? Thats the problem. The URL is not resolving corectly

Comment: @peeskillet When I access a API server, if I haven't started the API server, I get the net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. What does it mean?

Comment: It means you haven't started the server ;-) nothing to connect to

Comment: @peeskillet How should I handle this error to inform the user that the server hasn't been started?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131639/discussion-between-niaomingjian-and-peeskillet).